# Rails, Google Map does not display in Internet Explorer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I have an application that points to a client's specific locations based on the latitude and longitude that they enter in the CMS. It works perfectly fine in Chrome and in Firefox however it shows blank in IE 11 and I have no clue as to why. My home.js file has the following with tiny-slider being referenced at the top (also not working in IE):

```
import { tns } from 'tiny-slider/src/tiny-slider.module';
import { mapStyle } from './styles/mapStyle';

app.home = () => {
  function init() {
    setupSlider();
    startGoogleMap();
    let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('a.tab');
    for (let tab of tabs) {
      tab.addEventListener('click', tabClicked);
}
document.querySelector('#region-select_').addEventListener('change', selectClicked);
}

  let setupSlider = () => {
    const sliderOpts = {
      container: '.spud-banner-set',
      items: 1,
      slideBy: 'page',
      autoplay: true,
      controls: false,
      responsive: true,
      autoplayButtonOutput: false
    };

    const slider = tns(sliderOpts);
  };

  let startGoogleMap = () => {
    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-banner'), {
      zoom: 3,
      minizoom: 3,
      // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      gestureHandling: 'cooperative',
      styles: mapStyle
    });
    let mapElement = document.getElementById('map-banner');
    let pointMarkers = mapElement.getAttribute('data-location');
    let marked = JSON.parse(pointMarkers);
    let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    marked.forEach(marked => {
      if (marked.lat == null) return;
      if (marked.lng == null) return;

      const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(marked.lat, marked.lng),
        map: map,
        icon: '/marker.png',
        title: marked.name
      });
      bounds.extend(marker.position);
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  };

  let tabClicked = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const tabTarget = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-index');
    updateDisplayedTabs(tabTarget);
  };

  let selectClicked = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const tabTarget = e.target.value;
    updateDisplayedTabs(tabTarget);
  };

  let updateDisplayedTabs = tabTarget => {
    let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('a.tab');
    for (let tab of tabs) {
      const tabIndex = tab.getAttribute('data-index');
      if (tabIndex === tabTarget) {
        tab.classList = 'active tab';
      } else {
        tab.classList = 'tab';
      }
    }
    let tabContents = document.querySelectorAll('.region-tab');
    for (let content of tabContents) {
      const index = content.getAttribute('data-index');
      if (index === tabTarget) {
        content.setAttribute('data-active', 'true');
      } else {
        content.setAttribute('data-active', 'false');
      }
    }
  };

  return init();
};
```

I thought it could be a styling issue but I've literally gone through EVERY styling on the home page and stripped it out but never saw the map appear.

I have the following in my Home Page that shows the map:

```
=content_for :head do
 = javascript_include_tag "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#{ENV['MAP_KEY']}"
=content_for :body do
 .container-fluid
  .row
   #map-banner.banner[type="hidden" data-location=all_locations.to_json]
= render template: '/layouts/application'

javascript:
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', app.home);
```

I've also made sure that the application.html.slim file also has the DOCTYPE HTML present. The head also includes:

```
meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge'
```

The SCSS has the following for the banner:

```
#map-banner {
   height: 286px;
   width: 100%;
} 
.banner {
 position: absolute;
}
```

I'm also having issues using tiny-slider so I don't know if those are related or not.

Edit:
I did check the Console clicked on HTML1300: Navigation occurred. File: clientname.net and was prompted with: Could not locate webpack:///webpack/bootstrap numbersletters specified in source map https://clientname.net/packs/home-differentnumberletters.js.map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving this here for others if they come across it. Apparently it's an issue with Webpack and UglifyJS. Added the following to my environment.js file:

```
environment.plugins.get("UglifyJs").options.uglifyOptions.ecma = 5
```